# Simple Combination of cards

Tags: probability

I'm a bit ashamed to ask such a simple question, but my math skills are a bit rusty to say the least. Here's the big deal:

I have 10 cards, 5 black and 5 white. How many combination can I make with those cards while using all of them?

-Obviously permutating 2 same-color cards won't create a new combination.

I'd like to know the formula that I shall use in this situation.

Thanks

Fabien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to pick $5$ spots out of the $10$ for the white cards.  So you have ${10 \choose 5}=252$

Comment: I understand what you say, but I don't understand the  dollar character '$' in your formula. Do I need a plugin or something to read formulas?

Comment: The dollar signs indicate to Mathjax to format the math.  You should see large parentheses with 10 above 5 to show the value of 10 choose 5.  It renders fine here.  You might need a plugin

Comment: Thanks for the plugin, I thought that ${10 \choose 5}= 10!/(2*5!)$ = 15120. What is the good formula then?

Comment: @Fabinout:  No, ${n \choose r}=\frac {n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, so ${10 \choose 5}+\frac {10!}{5!5!}$.  Maybe a square of $5!$ became the multiply by $2$

Comment: That was exactly my problem, sorry for the inconvenience, thanks again. Have a good day.